# matching first three numbers in regex

Tags: php, regex

I have regex to match the US numbers:

```
\(?[2-9][0-8][0-9]\)?[-. ]?[0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}
```

Though I check first three digits as us numbers, I have few area code and want to filter numbrs with this area code only.

```
$area_code = array(201,202,203,2,04);
```

Number having first three digits among this array value should only allowed. what modification regex required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode) to join the numbers together with the delimiter `|` and use it in your regex pattern:

```
$area_code = array(201,202,203,204);
$p = implode('|', $area_code);
$pattern = '/\(?(?:'.$p.')\)?[-. ]?[0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}/';
```

The resulting regex would look like:

```
\(?(?:201|202|203|2|4)\)?[-. ]?[0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}
```

Which would match the number if they begin with one of the values in the  in the `$area_code` array. The advantage of this approach over the other one is that this'd let you add custom numbers that doesn't follow any specific pattern. The downside is that it can get slow if there *lots* of numbers in your array.

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/xZ4eM7)

Comment: thanks, here I have used it but it does not filter the number with listed code, can you please help http://ideone.com/oMdH7c

Comment: @user123: Ha, because you're missing the delimiters in your pattern. This should work: https://eval.in/141983

Comment: thank, can you please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299921/applying-or-operation-between-regex

Answer (score 1):

The following regular expression should serve your purpose:

```
\(?20[1-4]\)?[-. ]?[0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it reject `2`?

Comment: @AmalMurali The `2`is obviously a typo and should be `204`.

Comment: @Sharanya: thanks but my array value may grow to 21x, 2xx etc