# applying or operation between regex

Tags: php, regex

I have three different regex to validate the numbers. Each of them is not sufficient to filter all the numbers.

If I put or `|` operation among them then will it be good idea?

consider three regex:

1.

```
  '^\(?(?:(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-]?\(?|\+)44\)?[\s-]?\(?(?:0\)?[\s-]?\(?)?|0)(?:\d{2}\)?[\s-]?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4}|\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3,4}|\d{4}\)?[\s-]?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3})|\d{5}\)?[\s-]?\d{4,5}|8(?:00[\s-]?11[\s-]?11|45[\s-]?46[\s-]?4\d))(?:(?:[\s-]?(?:x|ext\.?\s?|\#)\d+)?)$^'
```

2.

```
(\+44)?\s?\(?0?\d{1,5}\)?\s\d{1,7}\s{0,1}\d{0,6}(?:\s-\s|\s)\s{0,2}\d{0,6}|(\+44)?\s?\(?\d{1,5}\)?\s\d{1,7}\s{0,1}\d{0,4}\s{0,1}\d{0,4}|(\+44)?\s?\(\d{1,5}\)\s?\d{3,7}\s?\d{0,4}\s?\d{0,4}|\d{4,5}\s*\d{3,5}\s\d{3,4}
```

3.

```
'/\(?[2-9][0-8][0-9]\)?[-. ]?[0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}/'
```

If I add `or` operation among these then how they will response?

If first regex does not match then only 2nd is cheked, if 1st, 2nd not matched then only match the 3rd?

or how the regex would be manipulated?

Comment: Why there is a `^` at the end of the first pattern? Do you use it as delimiter?

Comment: Did you try it? It ought to work, but nobody here has data to test it against & tell you if it works or not.

Comment: @Kryten: no, I did not try it, I wanted to know whether is it correct way to do or in appropriate? and also how does it perform `or`  among each other. in sequence?

Comment: The `or` operation works just like it would work in a programming language. As soon as a match is found, the other options following it are not checked. It would help us help you better if we knew what kind of patterns you intend to match with your regex.